# T::Balance ... associated type `Balance` not found for `T`

Tags: polkadot, rust

I was following this guide:

Configuring Genesis for Balances

https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/basics/genesis/

but got this error:

associated type Balance not found for T, associated type Balance not found

So where/what is the definition for this?

I think it is somewhere inside https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/pallet_balances/index.html

I tried this: type Balance: balances::Config::Balance;

then failed: expected trait, found associated type balances::Config::Balance not a trait

Please advise. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substrate chains are designed to be completely modular and without any assumptions about the underlying blockchain. This means that Balances are not necessarily a first class citizen within your runtime. Instead, if you want to use Balances in your chain, you need to follow a few common steps which you will see in most pallets.

1. Configure your chain to use a `Currency`:

   ```rust
   #[pallet::config]
   pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
       /// Currency type for this pallet.
       type Currency: ReservableCurrency<Self::AccountId>
           + LockableCurrency<Self::AccountId, Moment = Self::BlockNumber>;

       // ...
   }
   ```

   Note you may not need both `ReservableCurrency` and `LockableCurrency`, it depends on how you want to play with the currency.
2. Create a simple type alias to make it easier to access the `Balance` type inside of `Currency`:

   ```rust
   type BalanceOf<T> =
       <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;
   ```
3. Use this type alias wherever you want to use the Balance type:

   ```rust
   fn transfer(to: T::AccountId, from: T::Account, amount: BalanceOf<T>) -> DispatchResult { ... }
   ```

Comment: Wow. Thank you! But now I got this error: EncodeLike<u32> is not satisfied ... Please help! Thanks https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/998/trait-encodelikeu32-is-not-implemented-for-t-as-palletconfigcurrenc